Formula for sum of $n$ elements of sequence starting with $1, −3, 5, −7, 9, −11, 13, −15, \cdots$
This is problem from olimpic for highschoolers organized by AGH University of Science and Technology in Krakow.The orginal text is in polish. I know, that formula for n-th element of sequence would look like
$$(-1)^{n-1}    [2(n-1) + 1]$$

What is the question ? It is not difficult to guess this formula , that we have the odd numbers with alternating signs is immediately obvious.

In more formal terms, you are asking what $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1}(2n-1)$ is in terms of $N$. The formula for triangle numbers is a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula

The easiest approach would be to break the formula into two cases, depending on whether $~n~$ is odd or even, and provide a separate formula in each case.  Manual computation of the exact sum, for each $~n \in {4,5,6,7},~$ should be easy, the corresponding pattern in the data should be easy to discover and explain, and as a consequence, the problem will then be rendered trivial.

So check a few:

$S_1 = 1$
$S_2 = 1 - 3 = -2$
$S_3 = 1 - 3 + 5 = 3$
$S_4 = 1 - 3 + 5 - 7 = -4$
$S_5 = 1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 = 5$
$S_6 = 1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 - 11 = -6$

Can you write a formula for $S_n$ based on your observations of the pattern above?

is that enough? Don't you need some more complex proof?
i mean i saw that the solution will be:
n for not even n,
-n for even n,
but i didn't know that is enaugh

@MikseryAsta Once you got an intuition and that hypothesis, you may easily prove that by induction.
